# Powershell finding simple one liner for trimming text inside file

Tags: powershell

I have lots of files like this:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="UserName">mail.test@muzi.com</S>
      <SS N="Password">01000000d08c93c76b9</SS>
    </Props>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

i need to extract only the mail part : mail.text@muzi.com
i know i can use select-string and then trim from char to char, im looking for a simple one liner to find in each one of those files just the mail and trim it

```
$b = ($a | (select-string "username")).tostring()
$c = $b.trim(' ')
```

And so on..
Im sure theres a one liner to extract email from this but i cannot find it

Comment: _"im looking for a simple one liner"_  Why the insistence on a one liner?  You should prefer easy to read and maintain over "efficient" or "clever".

Comment: It doesnt have to be one liner but something much simplier than my workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) PowerShell ([`PSCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential)) object with a Password that is fabricated (or created under a different account):

> MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Deserialize" with "1"
> argument(s): "The parameter value "01000000d08c93c76b9" is not a valid
> encrypted string."

As you found yourself, if data comes from a file:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Credential | Export-Clixml .\Credential.xml
```

You might import and deserialize the object using the [`Import-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml) cmdlet:

```
$Credential = Import-clixml .\Credential.xml
$Credential.UserName
mail.test@muzi.com
```

In case the serialized string is resident in a variable (e.g. `$String`):

```
$String = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Credential)
```

You might deserialize the string using the [`Deserialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psserializer) method like:

```
[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($String).Username
mail.test@muzi.com
```

As it is [xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) based, you might also do this instead:

```
([Xml]$String).Objs.Obj.Props.S.'#text'
mail.test@muzi.com
```

> As a general note: it is usually a bad approach to directly peek
> and/or poke in serialized data using string cmdlets and/or methods
> along with `Select-String` and `-Replace`.

Comment: This looks like a good way but it doesnt seem to work i guess my syntax is wrong:
[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($Text).Username is the $text is the clixml or the raw data?

Comment: OMG. i can just (import-clixml file).username jeeez